# Better constraint on time Complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, breadth-first-search

Is the time complexity of this algorithm `O(V+E)` ? If not, can there be any modification that could lead to same results in `O(V+E)` time complexity.

```
bool Graph::hasP3() {
    vector<bool> visited(V, false);
    queue<int> Q;

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (!visited[i]) {
            visited[i] = true;
            Q.push(i);

            while (!Q.empty()) {
                int u = Q.front();
                Q.pop();

                for (int w : adj[u]) {
                    if (!visited[w]) {
                        visited[w] = true;
                        Q.push(w);
                    }

                    for (int x : adj[w]) {
                        if (x != u && find(adj[u].begin(), adj[u].end(), x) == adj[u].end()) {
                            return true; // Found a P3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

My analysis:
Every vertex is pushed into `Q` and popped out of `Q` exactly once. So that should contribute `O(V)` to the time complexity (I've dropped the constant `2`).
For every edge `u-v`, WLOG let's assume that `u` was pushed into `Q` before `v`.Then the edge `u-v` is accessed:

1. Once when `u` is popped out of `Q` and we are pushing all it's unvisited neighbours into `Q`.
2. Once every time we are finding any vertex x in neighbours of u, which is done as many times as there are nieghbours of `w`, for all `w` that are neighbours of u. This makes up for a total of sum of degrees of neighbours of `u`.
3. Once when `v` is popped out of `Q`.

So every edge `u-v` is accessed `2 + sum of degrees of of neighbours of u or v (depending on which of them entered Q first)`

Now I tried to think of an upper bound for this quantity that is more strict than just `O(E)`, which in turn makes the algorithm to be of time complexity `O(V+E^2)`.

I was wondering if there could be a more strict upper bound for the time complexity of this algorithm. Intuitively I think there should be one, because if we naively look at the time complextiy of `BFS`, it seems to be `O(V*E)`, but it is also `O(E+V)`. My goal was to acheive a time complexity of `O(E+V)`.

Any help is greatly apprecited, thanks.